# Ayuda error delphi xe7

Tags: windows, funciones, archivo, delphi, mips32

Me he descargado este codigo de fuente en delphi:
https://github.com/SamuelCFW/GTA-V-Console-Texture-Editor

Pero cuando voy a compilarlo me da error y no he podido solucionarlo,

Alguien me podria ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al primer error, si buscas ese componente en los ficheros verás que pone lo siguiente:

```
btnImport: TAeroButton;
```

No es un botón estandard (`TButton`) sino que es otro tipo de componente (`TAeroButton`). Antes de poder cargar el proyecto (y abrir los formularios) correctamente debes asegurarte de que tienes instalador esos componentes.

En la documentación de ese proyecto te dice que debes tener instalados estos 2 paquetes:

> ```
> * Vampyre Imaging Library: http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/
> * NTS Code Suite: http://code.google.com/p/nts-code-suite/
> ```

El segundo es el que incluye esos botones.

Por otro lado, si Delphi no encuentra un componente instalado al cargar un formulario, (como es este caso), elimnina su referencia para intentar continuar con la carga. en tu caso debe haberlos elimnado y de ahí ese error.

1) Instala los paquetes que aparecen máas arriba.
2) Vuelve a descargar el proyecto y cargalo de nuevo.

Comment: agregue todos los paquetes menos el de las imagenes, me pide que añada el archivo .dpk y dentro del paquete no lo tiene, alguna solucion?

Desde aqui instale el paquete nts code suite: https://i.imgur.com/evTDhVZ.png

Comment: Para instalar los paquetes debes compilar e instalar el DPK de cada uno de ellos. Una vez instalados en el IDE, a la hora de usarlos en otro proyecto como es tu caso, es posible que debas añadir los directorios con los fuentes (.PAS o .DCU) a los directorios de busqueda del proyecto.
Si te pide que instales todos los paqueteses debes hacerlo, si no te fallará al compilar.